# MVC 4 Passing View Model to controller - Using JavaScriptSerializer to Deserialize complex JSON Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am trying to Deserialise a JSON object in to a strongly typed .net object/Type. This is the object I want to create from the JSON

```
[Serializable]
public class CartItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SelectedProductOption> SelectedProductOptions { get; set; }
    public virtual Cart Cart { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

So you have the whole picture, I am also going to post the definition for the other objects that make up CartItem, but remember Its CartItem I want to ultimately end up with

```
[Serializable]
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}


[Serializable]
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
}
```

In my CartItem Object I have a collection of  SelectedProductOption (THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING PROBLEMS) This is the definition for a SelectedProductOption

```
[Serializable]
public class SelectedProductOption
{
    public Option Option { get; set; }
    public AllowedOptionValue Value { get; set; }
}
    [Serializable]
public class Option
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OptionName { get; set; }
    public virtual OptionGroup OptionGroup { get; set; }
}

    [Serializable]
    public class AllowedOptionValue
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Option Option { get; set; }
    public string OptionValue { get; set; }
    public string OptionCaption { get; set; }
    public decimal? PriceOffSet { get; set; }
    public bool? IsPercentageOffSet { get; set; }
 }
```

Now this is the JSON Object that I am trying to serialize

```
{\"Product\":{\"Id\":1,\"Price\":3.5,\"ProductName\":\"Rice Meal One\",\"Category\":         {\"Id\":1,\"CategoryName\":\" Rice Meals\",\"ImageURL\":\" \"},\"SelectedProductOptions\":[{\"Option\":{\"Id\":1,\"OptionName\":\"OptionName1\",\"OptionGroup\":{\"Id\":1,\"OptionGroupName\":\"Option Group\"}},\"Value\":{\"Id\":1,\"Option\":{\"Id\":4,\"OptionName\":\"OptionName2\",\"OptionGroup\":{\"Id\":1,\"OptionGroupName\":\"Option Group2\"}},\"OptionValue\":\"12123123\",\"OptionCaption\":\"12123123\",\"PriceOffSet\":3.2,\"IsPercentageOffSet\":true}},{\"Option\":{\"Id\":1,\"OptionName\":\"dsa\",\"OptionGroup\":{\"Id\":1,\"OptionGroupName\":\"asdas\"}},\"Value\":{\"Id\":1,\"Option\":{\"Id\":1,\"OptionName\":\"dsa\",\"OptionGroup\":{\"Id\":1,\"OptionGroupName\":\"asdas\"}},\"OptionValue\":\"12123123\",\"OptionCaption\":\"12123123\",\"PriceOffSet\":3.2,\"IsPercentageOffSet\":true}}]}}
```

So when I call:

```
CartItem cartItem = js.Deserialize<CartItem>(formData);
```

CartItem.Product has the right values
CartItem.Product.Category has the Right Values

but

CarItem.SelectedProductOptions is null...

Where am I going wrong? the only property that is not working, any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Do you need it just to pass the data from the View to controller?

Comment: Don't understand what you mean... because its quite a large object I am thinking maybe I should split it up and Deserialize it in maybe two stages and do the selected options separately @VladL

Comment: why did you tag the question with asp.net-mvc?

Comment: because Its an MVC app... The JSON object is coming from a view I am trying to convert that view model in to a 'cart item' object.. been stuck for a while now... thinking of changing my approach and maybe just passing some ID's and try and then create the cartitem on the server side.

Comment: @VladL does my question make sense? Dont really like post so much code.. but been stuck on this one for a while?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do it manually, asp.net MVC will do it for you :)

In view create a form, which contains all needed fields:

@model CartItem;

```
<form action="/mycontroller/myaction">

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => mode.ProductName)
    ...

    <button type=submit>OK</button>    
</form>
```

and define your controllers action like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult myaction(CartItem carItem)
{
 ...
}
```

the carItem object should contain all the data that you entered in the view